# R ==> Error: object 'MasterAcc' not found

Tags: r, loops, object

New to R.  I am getting "Error: object 'MasterAcc' not found" for the code below.  When I look at CM$Overall it is populated correctly.

```
for(j in 1:iterations)
{
   trainIndices = sample(seq(1:length(titanicClean$Age)1]), 
                         round(.7*length(titanicClean$Age)))
   trainTitanic = titanicClean[trainIndices,]
   testTitanic = titanicClean[-trainIndices,]


   trainTitanic$Survived = 
      factor(trainTitanic$Survived, labels=c("Not Survived", "Survived"))
   testTitanic$Survived = 
      factor(testTitanic$Survived, labels=c("Not Survived","Survived"))

   model = naiveBayes(trainTitanic[,c(3,6)], trainTitanic$Survived)
   table(predict(model, testTitanic[,c(3,6)]), 
         testTitanic$Survived)
CM = confusionMatrix(table(predict(model, 
   testTitanic[,c(3,6)]), testTitanic$Survived))
   MasterAcc[j] = CM$overall[1]
}

MeanAcc = colMeans((masterAcc))
MeanAcc
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. You have not defined `masterAcc`. Perhaps you should have initialized it as a list or matrix?  There's also a possibility that you don'r realize that exact spelling is needed and that "MasterAcc" != "masterAcc" and that "Overall" != "overall". I'm guessing that you are trying to follow some tutorial or another and have not entered all of the code, but that's just a guess based on several prior SO questions of a similar nature.

Comment: Thank you!  MasterAcc needed initialization.